# Как перенаправить вывод из скрипта запущенного через сервис systemd на монитор?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, systemd, raspbian

На **Raspi OS** (без GUI) запускается скрипт через **systemd**. Логи пишутся в `/var/log/logfile`. Нужно также выводить инфу для пользователей на монитор. При старте происходит вывод из systemd, на сколько понимаю, и еще из чего-то. Подскажите, как туда сделать вывод из **Bash**-скрипта?

Comment: `tail -f /var/log/logfile` например?

Comment: @andreymal, =) так мы делаем, да, но хорошо бы чтобы пользователь ничего не писал в терминал, чтобы он вообще не логинился, ему только нужно знать, что ПО сконфигурировалось и оборудование настроилось

Comment: как вариант, доработать код, чтобы он выводил более расширенный статус при запуске. либо попробовать через **tee** тот же файл через пайп запускать в стартовом скрипте.

Comment: Кажется я понял! Какой-то из `/dev/ttyXX` должен отвечать за вывод в этот терминальчик. Надо будет поэкспериментировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, вот мои наблюдения:

- Вывод stdout и stderr в нужную консоль `command &>> /dev/ttyX`, где X - это номер консоли (обычно от 1 до
  6).
- Переключаться между консолями можно вручную: **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + ( <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd> ).**
- Если у вас OS с GUI, то **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>** должен вернуть вас на Desktop.
- Также, что намного лучше, переключить можно прямо из bash-скрипта с помощью команды `chvt X`.
- А еще можно настроить автологин для нужной консоли через
  getty-сервис (systemd).
- RaspiOS без GUI по умолчанию выводит логи (в основном из systemd) в `/dev/tty1`.

Answer (score 1):

Просто посмотреть

```
journalctl -u rpiunit.service -e -f
```

Можно c rsyslog в терминал, я пишу в четвертый, пример /etc/rsyslog.conf

```
module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

*.*     /dev/tty4 # вывести весь лог в 4ую консоль
```